# C++ linking from project

Tags: c++, linker, glfw, glew

i want to link GLEW from my project folder, not from installing it under my installation directory of Visual studio, but it always gets me 'unresolved external symbol'. 
I don't want to link it from the installation path because i want this project to be portable, so what can I do? Tried everything seen here, but got nothing :( 
I tried the following:

```
Project properties -> Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories
```

I have pointed to their location, but nothing.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which libraries did you link? Which symbols are unresolved? Which library do those symbols belong to?

Comment: @nwp glew, glfw, glm :) EVERY one of them is unresolved.
Moved this project from my laptop

Comment: Did you link these libraries for the correct configurations? (Debug/Release)

Comment: @ArnavBorborah linked to all configurations.

Comment: Are you sure you told it to link the libraries and didn't just specify the library path?

Comment: @nwp guess we just found the problem :) I just specified the path, didnt did the linking, how can I do that in this case? This is the first time im trying to approach linking from a project folder.

Comment: Linking options are located at `Configuration properties` → `Linker`

Comment: @VTT i know that one :) thought i have to use a different method in this case